# How to "fix" my muddy backyard

Tags: home, gardening

1 year before: we bought a house
~5 months later: The backyard is muddy

I figured that the problem was the elevation, it looks something like this (\_), since its flat in the front, it got messed up by mud, is there anything i can do?
The warranty of the house came twice and did nothing more that just put grass on top of the mud (of course it did not worked at all)
What can I do?

Comment: Two typing characters don't really show the situation: but perhaps the warranty should include adequate drainage. In UK, anything you buy must be "fit for purpose." Like the roof doesn't let in rain, and you can sit in the garden in normal weather conditions.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The Sale Of Goods Act, to which you allude does not apply to gardens.  I speak from experience.  New-build snagging will replace turf but will not install additional drainage unless flood water enters the house within the two years.

Comment: This may be better suited on https://gardening.stackexchange.com/.  Installing drainage isn't really a lifehack.

Comment: @Chenmunka yes. I’d say nudge it over, but Gardening SE would require a few more details (e.g. what’s growing on the ground and hillside, existing landscaping structures...) and ideally photos. As it, it would be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option might be to build a drywell, assuming you cannot buid a conventional drain for some reason.

A drywell is a round pit that goes straight down and is filled with rocks and drains the water to a permeable layer. This only works if you have a permeable layer below the clay or whatever that is currently trapping the water. Permeable layers are generally course sand.

Of course, you can always hire a drilling company to find a deep permeable layer. When they dig the hole, they line it until it reaches the permeable layer. Can get expensive.

Comment: uhmm this works, but i dont wanna use rock (it rains a lot and its windy here, like, WINDY, and the rocks would disappear next morning, so yea, uhmm, they also recommended me something called french drain(or something like that, but the so so insurance just came and put some grass on top of the mud, so theres not much i can do except buying it :(. Anywaaaaysss... ill think about it thanks!

Comment: @Isaac750 A dry well and a french drain (for erosion prevention) are very similar that vary slightly with drainage options. Wind strong enough to dislodge rocks sounds as if mud is the least of your problems. Good luck!

Comment: @Stan what size of the rocks are you talking about? The wind does affect the mud, it dries up. But not enough, it only leaves a layer of dry mud (dirt), but when you step on it, your shoe will sink and it ain't pretty, so wind doesn'tat all help

Comment: @Isaac750 Drainage rock is usually 1.5" crushed gravel. A drywell or French drain  involves burying hundreds of pounds of gravel below grade - there's no way the wind is going to dislodge buried stone.

Answer (score 1):

You could add dirt to your yard to level it out. My grandparents had the same problem and they added dirt to the part of the yard that was flat and made it go at an angle so the water would not make the yard muddy.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your taste and inclination, embrace the opportunity and dig a pond. Have waterlilies and a few goldfish. Plant some shade and sit and watch birds bathing.

Declare this bug to be a feature.